# mysqli injected inside another class

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a function I have inside a class. $db is a mysqli object injected in at creation. I cannot get this to return any data. and cannot see where I have gone wrong. I have tried removing the if statement in case the problem was there.

```
function getStat($statName) {
    /**
     * Gets latest value assigned to the statName for the given charID
     */

    $sql = "select statValue from charStat where charID =".$this->charID." and statName =".$statName." order by timerstamp DESC limit 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows == '1'){
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        return $row[0];
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Probably `$row[0]` is just empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to change:

```
} else {
    return "error";
}
```

To this to display the error:

```
} else {
    return mysql_error();
}
```

This should return the last MySQL error message, unless the connection to the database is closed in the db->query call.

That is...if it's returning "error". If not, then $row[0] is empty. You'd need to show the code from the $db class to figure out more information.

Comment: This got it to spit out an error message that I could work with, I now feel like such an idiot. thanks for the help